# MFMailComposer not working in io6 landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposeController=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailComposeController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
  //  mailComposeController.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    [mailComposeController setSubject:@"WallPaperApp."];
    [mailComposeController setMessageBody:@"This is my new Wallpaper." isHTML:NO];
    UIImage *img=mainImageView.image;
    UIImage *img1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"aaa.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);      
    [mailComposeController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo.png"]];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposeController animated:YES];
    //[mailComposeController release];

}
```

its working fine in ios5 but not working in ios6 m testing on device

Comment: Try this once.    mailComposeController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

Comment: what is img1 for? (just trying to understand it :D)

Comment: actually img1 is nothing,usless obj,plz help if anyone know,m stuck here

Comment: does your the viewController presenting your mailComposer rotates to landscape in ios6?

Comment: my app is in landscape only,so its not working in ios6 but working perfectly fine in ios5

Comment: mmmh, seems odd... you might want to try to subclass MFMailComposeViewController and ovverride the rotation methods for ios5/ios6, not sure it would work but it's worth a try

Comment: **add a property in your .h file like this @property(nonatomic,retain) MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposeController; and synthesize it and try again.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code in didfinishloading in appdelegate

```
rootController = 
    [[firstViewController alloc] 
     initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];
        window = [[UIWindow alloc] 
                  initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

rootController is a uiviewcontroller instance

Comment: i don't think that it will correct the problem, the app works well for every viewControllers, there is only the MFMailComposeViewController that doesn't show well.

Comment: i have also the similar problem in rotating, the issue solved using the above change
please implement and let me know